# Jacobian matrix in calculus

Tags: calculus

Suppose a Jacobian matrix is made from a 3D parametric equation(no other form of the equation is know for eg Cartesian equation).Is the volume of the determinant of this Jacobian matrix the same as the volume of the parametric equations?

I asking this because in Wolfram they integrate the determinant of the Jacobian matrix to determine the volume of a torus. And the theory for changing variable says that the Jacobian is multiplied with the original function(below is a screenshot from wolfram and the Jacobian change in variable rule):

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The volume of the torus is given by $V=\int_RdV$, thus, the “original function” before the change of variables is $1$. When you change variables, you multiply this by $\operatorname{Det}J$, which of course makes the new integrand simply $\operatorname{Det}J$.

Comment: the original function will be the cartesian form of the parametric equation right?

Comment: and why is the original function 1?

Comment: Think of $f$ in the integral $\int_Rf(x,y,z)\;dV$ as a mass density, so that the integral computes the total mass of the solid. If you set the density to a constant $1$, the mass will numerically equal the volume. In other words, if you want the volume, you compute $\int_R 1\;dV=\int_RdV$.

Comment: But in this case f(x,y,z) won't be 1 right?

Comment: No. If the volume of a solid is given by $\int_RdV=\int_Rf(x,y,z)\;dV$, then what is $f$?

Comment: f will be the cartesian form of the parametric equation right?

Comment: Wrong. Forget the torus and its parametric equations for now. $\int_a^b\int_c^d\int_e^fdx\;dy\;dz$ gives the volume of a rectangular solid, right? When you write that as $\int_Rf(x,y,z)\;dV$, the $dV$ just stands for $dx\;dy\;dz$, so $f$ has to be $1$. It’s the same for the torus, except that the bounds are ugly functions of $x$, $y$ and $z$. The parametric equations and Jacobian come in when you do a substitution into the integral to make those bounds simpler.

Comment: OH.... So basically the R that you wrote there was the function itself, and it acted as the bounds for the integral?

Comment: I think I understand now

Comment: If what I said was correct

Comment: Thank you very much. It makes much more sense now

Comment: Looks like you’ve basically got it. The $R$ just represents the region of integration without reference to any particular coordinate system. When you express the integral in Cartesian coordinates, you use the equations for $R$ in $x$, $y$ and $z$ to determine the bounds of the three integrals. You then substitute the parametric equations to make it simpler, turning it into an integral over $r$, $u$ and $v$. In one dimension, you’d replace $dx$ by $\frac{dx}{du}du$; in three you replace $dx\;dy\;dz$ with $\left|\frac{\partial(x,y,z)}{\partial(r,u,v)}\right|dr\;du\;dv$.

Comment: I understand now, thank you so much